# how to remove URL/___from_store=xx

Tags: magento2.2.3

How to remove `URL/___from_store=xx?...` it's showing url like `?___from_store=en`

Please help!

I am using **Magento 2.2.3**. I added this code in `/magento/module-store/model/Store.php` but it's not working:

```
/**
 * To clean URL from wrong query string
 *
 * @return Cleaned url
 */
public function cleanUrlQueryString($url)
{
    if(preg_match("/\?/", $url)){
        $arr = explode('?', $url);
        $queryArray = false;
        if(isset($arr[1])){
            $strArr = parse_str(html_entity_decode($arr[1]), $queryArray);
        }
        $cleanedUrl = $arr[0];
        $cleanedUrl .= ($queryArray) ? '?'.http_build_query($queryArray, '', '&amp;') : '';
        return $cleanedUrl;
    } 
    return $url;        
}
```

Comment: It is not right to modify in **Magento CORE**.

Comment: so how can i remove ?___store=XX&___from_store=XX..can you help? @St3phan

Comment: @niceonelee Did you get soulution, can you please share. I want to do same.

Answer (score 0):

I did it so ... In Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Store\Controller\Store\Redirect" type="Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Store\Controller\Store\Redirect" />
```

copy in Vendor\Module\Rewrite\Magento\Store\Controller\Store\Redirect all code from Magento\Store\Controller\Store\Redirect . Find row with code

```
$query = array_merge($query, $customerHash);
```

and add after this row

```
if(isset($query['___from_store'])){
    unset($query['___from_store']);
}
```

that's all.